# MYSQL ENTIRE DATABASE WITH MYSQL EVENT SCHEDULER

Tags: mysql, database, backup, scheduler

would like some tips on how to make a backup of a mysql database with Event Scheduler

I just got in my research,i only find how to backup tables individually.

I wish I could back up the entire database, someone help me?

"ATENTION I´M TESTING IN LOCALHOST,SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH"

MY WRONG CODE BELOW:

```
SET @sql_text = 
   CONCAT (
   "SELECT * FROM ?i dont know? INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Eiglimar\Desktop\backup_mysql"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
   , "BonInterne.csv'"
);

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;

delimiter |

CREATE EVENT BackUpCSV
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE s1;
  END |

delimiter ;

DROP PREPARE s1;
```